# Remove a confirm() dialog via javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a javascript function, I do this for quick prototyping:

```
if(confirm("are you sure you want to do this")) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

If I get a specific event over a websocket, I want to remove this dialog in javascript/jquery. Any ideas how to do that? Is there a DOM id or something for that? Extra-Points if not even the else-block is executed when removing the dialog :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. All javascript execution is halted while a `confirm`, `alert`, or `prompt` is displayed.

> Dialog boxes are modal windows - they prevent the user from accessing
>   the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed.
>   For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a
>   dialog box (or modal window).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm